# Has anyone implemented authentication for ADFS auth server using MSAL4J java library in a web application?

Tags: java, adfs, azure-ad-msal

Referenced documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/msal/adfs-msal-web-api-web-api

The auth grant type preferred is - implicit type

I am looking for approach and some sample application or links where this solution is implemented using Java, springBoot.

Below is the msal4j dependency:

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
 <artifactId>msal4j</artifactId>
  <version>0.5.0-preview</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The link you shared is pointing to a tutorial on how to use MSAL .NET with ADFS 2019. MSAL4J currently does not support ADFS 2019, although it is on the backlog. You can track progress of this [feature](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/issues/51) on GitHub.

For a spring boot sample that works with Azure AD and MSAL4J, I would recommend you take a look at the [MSAL4J springboot web application sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapp)